# How to generate QR codes using library in .Net

Tags: qr-code

I am planning to explore on QR code generation . I saw the google api http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=75x75&chl=test and its pretty impressive. But it works only for URL's and small data's. So i am thinking about writing a .net app to generate the QR code. So any information on libraries to start with ,will be helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It does not just work for URLs. You can put whatever text you want as an argument (just URL-encode it correctly). It also works for any data size that QR codes can support.

Comment: I am not sure ,which one you are refering here. Google API works for URL's. http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=75x75&chl=www.google.com

Comment: Yes, and it works for any text you want, not just URLs: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chl=ham+sandwich  Trust me, I was one of the people that help get this API set up.